# Actionscript 3 - Toggling visible status of a Movie Clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have a MovieClip of instance name BeachMovie.

On the same frame I have another MovieClip, inside this MovieClip is actionscript that will play sounds and toggle pictures on and off. It is also used so that when pressed the .visible status of BeachMovie is toggled on and off.

How can I communicate with BeachMovie MovieClip when the actionscript to do it is used (and is needed) within another Movieclip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally your instance names should begin with a lowercase letter.

Try

```
this.parent.beachMovie.visible = false;

or MovieClip(root).beachMovie.visible = false;
```